# Calculate a percentage based on some value in my table

Tags: reporting-services

I have this table, and I want to calculate this formula and get the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in SQL rather than in an SSRS expression as it will be much easier.

The following query shows how to get to the answer based on your sample data. I've also included some additional columns in the output so that you can see how each part is derived.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Question varchar(10), [Value] int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Rate', 10),
('Rate', 10),
('Rate', 1),
('Rate', 2),
('Rate', 10),
('Rate', 9),
('Rate', 9),
('Rate', 6),
('Rate', 5),
('Rate', 4),
('Rate', 3),
('Rate', 4)


SELECT 
    *
    , HiPc = cast(HiCount as float)/cast(TotalCount as float) 
    , MidPc = cast(midCount as float)/cast(TotalCount as float) 
    , Answer = (cast(HiCount as float)/cast(TotalCount as float)) - cast(midCount as float)/cast(TotalCount as float)
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) TotalCount FROM @t) t ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as HiCount FROM @t WHERE [Value] IN (9,10)) h ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as MidCount FROM @t WHERE [Value] IN (5,6)) m
```

This gives us the following output (I've trimmed some of the numbers for clarity)

```
TotalCount  HiCount MidCount    HiPc    MidPc   Answer
12          5       2           0.41667 0.16666 0.25
```

As you can see we get the desired output of 0.25 (25%)

Comment: Thank you Alan, but i'm working with Reporting Services. i have many charts and graph in my report, and i one if my matrix table i would like to get the result explained.

Comment: I meant that if you work this out in SQL you can add the result to your dataset and then it would be available to use in your report.